# How do I query a table in SQL to produce a result where column names are stacked vertically based on a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, common-table-expression, temp

Suppose I have a SQL table titled Users with the following example data:

```
Description          Days
--------------------------
Healthy               10
High-blood pressure   20          
Cholesterol           23 
Diabetes              31
High-blood pressure   8
Healthy               12
Diabetes              18              
Cholesterol           25
High-blood pressure   20
Healthy               6
```

How would I produce a result that looks like the following where the columns: Less_than_20_days, 20_days and Greater_than_20_days contains counts from the table above

```
Description         Less_than_20_days         20_days         Greater_than_20_days
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Healthy                    3                     0                     0
High-blood pressure        1                     2                     0
Cholesterol                0                     0                     2
Diabetes                   1                     0                     1
```

I'm trying to get this to work in SQL Server and have tried using the union operator, temp tables and ctes but I can't seem to get the desired result.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `case` with `sum()`:

```
select
     [Description]
    ,sum(case when [Days] < 20 then 1 else 0 end) as Less_than_20_days
    ,sum(case when [Days] = 20 then 1 else 0 end) as d20_days
    ,sum(case when [Days] > 20 then 1 else 0 end) as Greater_than_20_days
from users
group by [Description]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select description,
       sum(case when days < 20 then 1 else 0 end) as num_lt_20,
       sum(case when days = 20 then 1 else 0 end) as num_eq_20,
       sum(case when days > 20 then 1 else 0 end) as num_gt_20
from t
group by description
```